# Is it possible to batch test a list of proxy in terminal?

Tags: terminal

traditionally testing a proxy is to use telnet to connect a proxy server and then connect a url to see if the proxy is up and running. Is it possible to test, let's say a list of 100 proxies, to a specific url with only a few lines of commands?

This is the traditional method:

```
telnet www.proxy.com 8080
telnet: Trying 192.0.0.1...
telnet: Connected to 192.0.0.1.
CONNECT www.google.com:80 HTTP/1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is actually a npm tool called proxy-checker that does exactly what you ask (https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy-checker). There is no easy way to terminate proxy connections automatically while hooking up new ones. It requires some type of web frameworks (here it is node.js) to allow such action to be complete efficiently (correct me if wrong). I think php or python frameworks can do similar things but I usually just go for the node.js-powered proxy-checker. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe a textfile as input into a program using the < command.

So lets say you have a textfile called: MyFile.txt and it has the following info:

```
CONNECT www.google.com:80 HTTP/1.0
bye
```

And you have a batchfile that connects, it would look like this:

```
telnet www.proxy.com 8080 < MyFile.txt
```

It would then do exactly the above. Open telnet, and automatically input the command.
Note that I entered an extra white row in my example. This is to simulate an enter at the end of the row. Its important this enter is in your textfile because that enter will be sent along too.

Additionally you can use >> to send the output of the command to a textfile.

For example:

```
echo telnetting to www.proxy.com 8080 >> mylog.txt
telnet www.proxy.com 8080 < MyFile.txt >> mylog.txt
echo. >>mylog.txt
```

mylog.txt would then show the following:

```
telnetting to www.proxy.com 8080
Trying 192.0.0.1...
Connected to 192.0.0.1.
<output of the CONNECT command>
Disconnecting...
```

And since we place `echo.`, which is an empty row, there will also be an empty row.

Comment: There are two problems. One being the terminal will not terminate telnet automatically if the proxy is dead, second being if the proxy cannot connect to the url, the terminal would also not terminate it automatically...

Comment: I found a online checker here: www.checker.freeproxy.ru/checker/ but unfortunately it doesn't allow us to select a destination. I assume they check the proxy against their own server - which is in Russia and not too useful.